# Can't reach value in async function with setInterval - JavaScript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, async-await, setinterval

I'm trying to do automated card pull started with button, and stop it when `croupierCount` reach 17, using `setInterval`. Value of `croupierCount` changes (`<div>` displays this count) with this function below, but when I'm trying to reach this value inside function to stop interval, it's logged value is 0. Can you help me solve this?

```
const TheGame = () => {

  const [croupierCount, setCroupierCount] = useState(0);
  const [croupierHand, setCroupierHand] = useState([]);

  const onStandHandler = () => {            // triggered with button

     const croupierInterval = async () => {
        
        let card = await fetchCard(deck);  // fetching new card with every iteration (works) 
        croupierHand.push(card);  // pushes fetched card (works)
    
        if (card[0].value === 'ACE') {
            setCroupierCount((prevCount) => prevCount + 11);
        }
    
        else if (card[0].value === 'JACK' || card[0].value === 'QUEEN' || card[0].value === 'KING') {
            setCroupierCount((prevCount) => prevCount + 10);
        }
        else {
            setCroupierCount((prevCount) => prevCount + Number(card[0].value));
        };         
                                                         
        // croupierCount is changing (I'm displaying it in div)

        console.log(croupierCount); // croupierCount = 0, I don't know why.

        if(croupierCount > 17) {
            clearInterval(startInterval);
        };
    }

    const startInterval = setInterval(croupierInterval, 1000);

  };
};
```

Comment: You're using `croupierCount` as if it is a global variable. Is it? Crucial code to debug your problem is missing. Where is the code that gives `croupierCount` its value?

Comment: My apologies, I've cutted wrong fragment. Now it's edited @KIKOSoftware.

Comment: What triggers onStandHandler?

Comment: @raina77ow - button

Comment: shouldn't it be `setCroupierCount(croupierCount + 11);`? https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html

Comment: @GrafiCode It doesnt count it properly like this. And even changed so, still gives me value of 0 at point of `console.log`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm posting my solution, if someone encounters a similar problem.

```
const isMount = useRef(false);

...

useEffect(() => {
  
    if (isMount.current && croupierCount !== 0) {
        
        if (croupierCount < 17) {
            setTimeout(() => {
                onStandHandler();
            }, 1000);
        }
    }

    else isMount.current = true;
}, [croupierCount]);

const onStandHandler = async () => {

        let card = await fetchCard(deck, 1);
        croupierHand.push(card);
    
        if (card[0].value === 'ACE') {
            setCroupierCount(prevCount => prevCount + 11);
        }
    
        else if (card[0].value === 'JACK' || card[0].value === 'QUEEN' || card[0].value === 'KING') {
            setCroupierCount(prevCount => prevCount + 10);
        }
        else {
            setCroupierCount(prevCount => prevCount + Number(card[0].value));
        };    
};
```

Answer (score 1):

You seem to miss an important point: using `const` here...

```
const [croupierCount, setCroupierCount] = useState(0);
```

... makes `croupierCount` a **constant** value, regardless of how many times `setCroupierCount` is called. This variable cannot be updated directly: what you see as its update is actually changes in React internal state, represented by the same name when the component is rerendered - and render function is called again.

This immutability is both a blessing and a curse typical to hook-based functional components.

---

Here's what happens here:

- when component is rendered, `TheGame` function is called first time. Its `useState` call initializes both value and the corresponding setter as a part of internal React state tied to this component's instance.

Those values are returned from `useState` function - and are stored in local variables (constants!) of `TheGame` function, `croupierCount` and `setCroupierCount`. What's important - and often missed - is that these particular variables are created anew **each time `TheGame` function is called**!

- then `onStandHandler` function is created, having both aforementioned local variables available as part of its scope.
- at some point, `onStandHandler` function is triggered (when user presses a button). It creates yet another function, `croupierInterval`, which should fetch data first, then update the state by calling `setCroupierCount` with result of this fetch.

There are two problems with this function, though.

First, all `croupierInterval` sees is values of *current* `croupierCount` and `setCroupierCount` variables. It cannot magically 'peek' into which values those variables will carry when rerender is triggered and `TheGame` function is executed next time - as those will be new variables actually!

But there's a bigger problem you seem to miss: `setInterval` doesn't play nicely with `fetch` (or any async action). Instead of waiting for the processing of that action, you just make JS trigger this function periodically.

Not only this messes up with an expected delay (slow down `fetch` so that it takes 10 seconds, then see what happens), but there's an actual bug here: as `clearInterval(startInterval)` doesn't stop processing all the parts of a function that follow `await fetchCard(deck)`, in the worst case, your Croupier might go way above 17.

---

This is for 'why' part, but what's on 'how to fix'? There are several things worth trying here:

- avoid using setInterval in functional components like a plague: there are often far better replacements. In this case in particular, you should've at least tied setting up calling `croupierInterval` to the previous call's completion
- `useEffect` whenever you want something to modify your state indirectly as some kind of side-effect. Not only this makes your code easier to read and understand, but also lets you clear out the side effects of side effects (like timeouts/intervals set)
- don't forget to handle human errors, too: what should happen if a user mistakenly double-clicks this button?

Comment: Thank You for the informations. Do recommend any other approach to this problem?

Comment: At the very least, get rid of interval and call the fetcher function right at the end of executing the first loop. In general, consider using `useEffect` hook to trigger such things; this will let you cancel the delayed action if user goes away and the action is no longer needed.